# What is the best order for several buttons at the foot of a modal?

Tags: buttons, modal-dialog

I have a multipage modal I am creating. So I have Previous, Next, and Cancel buttons. In addition, since their are many steps, some of which could be blockers, I am giving the user to ability to save their work to the point where they hit a blocker. So I added a Save and Close button. What is the best order for these. Please note that, Save and Cancel, and Previous are not on the opening screen. Next becomes Done on the final screen. Next and Done are both colored as a primary button, and Cancel is a link.

My current iteration:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flGO5a.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose there could be better options:
[image]
Features are:

1. Clear primary activity buttons (`Previous`, `Next`).
2. Clear `Close` button on the top right. And...
3. Smart 'Close' button, which auto-saves settings without user disturbance. When user again initiates the dialog the system propose to start it from the beginning or continue from the previous step.

Considering frequency and importantness of `Save and close` action, you could display it as a secondary action link. But name it more appropriate to the task flow, i.e. `Continue later`. This explicitly says to user its functionality. 
[image]

Comment: I like the continue later. I think the "x" close in the upper left works for non-essential things like lightboxes, but as this application is a business app, I feel I need to be more explicit.

Comment: I initially liked the continue later, then wondered if that is a little ambiguous. Does it save my work? "Save and continue later" may inspire more user confidence. Thoughts?

Comment: @uxzapper "Save" is a bit tech internal detail, the next question could be "Where to save? And then how to open?", etc. So "Continue later" sounds a bit user-friendlier. Although this point not so critical and your option is good, too.